# Buffer need free when process done or not?

Tags: node.js, buffer

I'm working with Buffer in Node js, this is the first time i work with it. I don't know Buffer is free when finish a process or not, for example (file uploaded is store in memmoryStore):

```
app.post('/uploadavatar', function (req, res, next) {
        upload(req,res,function(err){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Done !");
            }
        });
})
```

Is buffer free when process `upload` done ?

When i run process for 20000 time with loop

```
app.post('/uploadavatar', function (req, res, next) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 20000; i++){
        upload(req,res,function(err){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("done: " + i);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

It have a error (server test is 2GB ram, file upload: 200kb), it say `memory leak`

Buffer need free when process `upload` done or not ?

Comment: Is it possible that the `upload` function takes a long time to run and/or holds on to resources for a long time? Can you provide an overview of the `upload` function?

Comment: @Behrooz I'm using [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to upload image from client. And using `memoryStorage` instead of `DiskStorage`. Because i want to check type and size exacly by [imageinfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imageinfo), it need buffer to do it, so i use memoryStoreage